# why python appiumService cannot use address 0.0.0.0?

Tags: python-appium

I am using Python AppiumService to start my appium server

```
from appium.webdriver.appium_service import AppiumService

service = AppiumService()

args = [
    "--address", "127.0.0.1", # this works
    #"--address", "0.0.0.0",  # this works on cmd line, but not in script. Why?
    "--port", "4723",
    "--log-no-colors",
    "--base-path", '/wd/hub'
]

print(f"starting cmd = appium {' '.join(args)}")
service.start(args=args)
print(f"service.is_running={service.is_running}")
print(f"service.is_listening={service.is_listening}")
service.stop()
```

If I use the localhost address 127.0.0.1 as listening address, it works.

```
C:\Users\...> python myscript.py
starting cmd = appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --log-no-colors --base-path /wd/hub
service.is_running=True
service.is_listening=True
```

But if I use the wildcard address 0.0.0.0, which should be the default address, it doesn't work

```
C:\Users\...> python myscript.py
starting cmd = appium --address 0.0.0.0 --port 4723 --log-no-colors --base-path /wd/hub
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\...\test_appiumService.py", line 14, in <module>
    service.start(args=args)
  File "c:\users\...\site-packages\appium\webdriver\appium_service.py", line 222, in start
    raise AppiumServiceError(error_msg)
appium.webdriver.appium_service.AppiumServiceError: Appium server has started but is not listening on /wd/hub/status within 60000ms timeout. Make sure proper values have been provided to --base-path, --address and --port process arguments.
```

The 0.0.0.0 address works fine on command line

```
c:\Users\...>appium --address 0.0.0.0 --port 4723 --log-no-colors --base-path /wd/hub
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   logNoColors: true
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Environment:

```
Windows 10 latest patch, 
Python 3.10, 
Appium server 1.22.3, 
Appium-Python-Client 2.7.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same when setting up my test project. I'm guessing the reason could be that 0.0.0.0 cannot be pinged and for some reason starting it via code requires a ping, while starting the server yourself does not. But it's a guess, I'm really not sure.

Comment: I agree. the code seems to ping 0.0.0.0 as both IPV4 and IPV6. The ping failed at the later